# How to pass URL from another URL out put To HTTP connection manager dynamically

Tags: ssis

I need to develop one SSIS package. Below is the requirement

I have One URL, which returns output as "another URL"
I need to pass that URL to Http Connection manager to download the data.

Can you please let me know how can we achieve this using Script task in SSIS

Answer (score 0):

If your source URL call is returning output then this might work.

Create a string variable named URL and enter your source URL into this variable.  In a C# script task, add the URL variable as your ReadOnlyVariable then add this code below.

```
string strURL = (string)Dts.Variables["URL"].Value;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(strURL);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string strNewURL = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

strNewURL should contain your new URL output.